# Has anyone configured Kerberos SSO on Web Logic 12.1.2 with JDK 1.7 on Win 2012 successfully?

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to configure **Kerberos SSO on Web Logic 12.1.2 with JDK 1.7.x on Win 2012 R2**. I am using `Java ktab java command to create keytab file`. The encryption includes **DES and rc4-hmac**. My **kerberos ini file** only uses **rc4-hmac encryption**.
But when I try to login to my application I am getting this error in Web Logic log file (fragment):

```
####<Nov 13, 2014 7:24:29 AM PST> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <ifvm00131> <ICN_ManagedServer_2> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1415892269395> <BEA-000000> <acceptGssInitContextToken failed
com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)
    at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.acceptGssInitContextTokenInDoAs(KerberosTokenHandler.java:351)
    at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.access$100(KerberosTokenHandler.java:43)
    at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler$2.run(KerberosTokenHandler.java:239)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.acceptGssInitContextToken(KerberosTokenHandler.java:237)
    at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.acceptGssInitContextToken(KerberosTokenHandler.java:165)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.negotiate.SPNEGONegotiateToken.getUsername(SPNEGONegotiateToken.java:57)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NegotiateIdentityAsserterProviderImpl.assertChallengeIdentity(NegotiateIdentityAsserterProviderImpl.java:210)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.legacy.service.ChallengeIdentityAssertionProviderImpl$ChallengeIdentityAsserterV2Adapter.assertChallengeIdentity(ChallengeIdentityAssertionProviderImpl.java:130)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.ChallengeIdentityAssertionTokenServiceImpl.assertChallengeIdentity(ChallengeIdentityAssertionTokenServiceImpl.java:120)
```

and login to my application is unsuccessful. I am getting in browser Error **401--Unauthorized error**.

When I reconfigure the env using the **AES256 encryption** I am getting Checksum failed error.

I wonder if anyone experienced similar issues and was able to resole it successfully?

Here is my krb5.ini file located in the c:\windows directory

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYREALM.LOCAL
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
    default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
    ticket_lifetime = 600

[realms]
    MYREALM.LOCAL = {
        kdc = adhostname.mydomain.local:88
        admin_server = adhostname.mydomain.local
        default_domain = mydomain.local
    }

[domain_realm]
    mydomain.local = MYREALM.LOCAL
    .mydomain.local = MYREALM.LOCAL
```

And this is my config file

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate 
{
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   principal="account@REALM.LOCAL" useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="C:\\sso\\wlker.keytab" storeKey=true debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept 
{
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule Required
   principal="account@REALM.LOCAL" useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="C:\\sso\\wlker.keytab" storeKey=true debug=true;
};

Myapp
{
weblogic.security.auth.login.UsernamePasswordLoginModule required authOnLogin=true;
};
```

Comment: Why is the principal realm different to the realm in the krb5.conf?

Comment: Well spotted but in this example this is just a typo sorry. It is MYREALM.LOCAL In my real env they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this before. Please search, you have to enable/install unlimited security policy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have added that I am not using AES256 encryption, I am using rc4-hmac encryption and yet I am still getting error regarding AES256 encryption. I also tried to fully reconfigure my env with AES256 encryption including replacing unlimited security policy JDK 1.7 jar file but I got different error as i mentioned above Checksum failed error.

Comment: @Irina, well someone selects AES256, probably your client. Please post your full `krb5.conf` in your question.

Comment: I replaced principal and realm names to more generic for this post.

Comment: mydomain.local is the same name as MYREALM.LOCAL

Comment: Apologies. I am using this site for the first time. I added both files to my question above.

Comment: @Irina, you should check what type of encryption your client uses. It selects the strongest enc available.

Comment: My client is Win7 Ultimate. According to Windows TechNet Library RC4-HMAC encryption is enabled by default. When I check settings in The Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos policy setting located in Computer Configuration\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options it was set to Not Enabled. I selected RC4-HMAC encryption but this did not resolve the problem. Could it be somewhere is registry perhaps?

Comment: Inspect the client-bound traffic with Wirshark.